# gnu screen /dev/tty autocomplete

Tags: 16.04, serial-port

I run Ubuntu 16.04 and use `screen` to connect with USB to Serial ports `/dev/ttyUSB0`, `/dev/ttyUSB1`, and so on.
I add $USER to `dialout` and to `uucp` groups and I can access `/dev/ttyUSB0` without root. But when I type `screen /dev/ttyU` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the autocomplete doesn’t work.

If I run `sudo su` then `screen /dev/ttyU` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the autocomplete works. What could be causing this?

The file rights are as follows:

```
crw-rw----  1 root dialout 188,   0 Sep 14 15:26 ttyUSB0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `$USER`'s screen configured to use a different shell than `root`'s?

Comment: Yes, I can run it without root privilege.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but this is the only one I could find.
I had the same issue using raspberry pi with a usb to rj45 console cable to connecto to a Cisco device.
I solved it by adding the pi user to the tty group.
command:
sudo usermod -a -G tty pi

replace pi with your username if it's different.